# Better way to limit the unix command find by filename

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I'm getting results using find with filenames that have '~' and .swp, etc. So I did the following, but is there a better way to do this? The `'.*.js' -iname '*.js'` part feels "redundant".

```
$ find ./ '.*.js' -iname '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n ".*loginError.*"
find: `.*.js': No such file or directory
./js/signin.js:252:                               foo.loginError();
./js/signin.js:339:foo.loginError = function() {
./js/signin.js:340:    foo.log("ui.loginError");
```

Comment: Your '.*.js' parameter IS redundant, it is interpreted as a relative path name to your current location (it isn't used as a pattern in the find) and as you can see, causes find to print an error (the first line in the output)

Comment: Also redundant are the `.*` at both ends of your `grep` pattern. You can simply omit them. `grep -n "loginError"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
find . -name \*.js -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n ".*loginError.*"
```

That will find only files with 'js' extension and not ending in ~ or .swp

EDIT: Added '0' -print0 (edit requires 6 characters so I'm adding this; ergh!)

Answer (score 1):

To do it all in one command without the xargs you could do it like this

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec grep -n ".*loginError.*" /dev/null {} \;
```

the /dev/null piece is to make grep think it's searching multiple files and then it'll output the filename correctly, otherwise it'd just print out the line number without telling you which file it's in

Comment: an alternative way to print the filenames is `find . -name "*.js" -exec grep -n "loginError" {} \; -print` - I also removed the `.*`s from grep, which just infects what is colorized (pattern/whole line).